# I am confused when i should use these

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am really confused about when I should use these,

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You add `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` if you want Django to serve *static files* in development mode, and you add `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` if you want Django to serve *media files* in development mode.

If you want to serve both, you can work with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # … the rest of your URLconf goes here …
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In production (when `DEBUG = False`), Django does *not* serve static/media files, in that case you should configure the webserver (apache, nginx, etc.) to serve these files. Or work with [*WhiteNoise*](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/).